# Twilio account trail number

Tags: twilio

I am new to Twilio account and stuck in finding the trail number for my account but unable to locate it.

Please can I get some help to know the steps/link to find it.

Thanks
Balaji

Comment: Have you checked out [the Incoming Numbers section of the Twilio console](https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/incoming)?

Comment: @philnash, thank you for the response. I tried under 'Buy a Number' section to got a trial one. I thought it is a real purchase which made me to post this question.

Comment: On a trial account you can purchase one number and it won't cost you anything for the duration of your trial.

Answer (score 0):

The FAQ gives you a rundown of how the [trial works](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223136107-How-does-Twilio-s-Free-Trial-work-).

Once you "purchase" your trial number (it won't cost you anything for the duration of your trial), you can [make calls](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls):

```
# Download the Python helper library from twilio.com/docs/python/install
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient

# Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
account_sid = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
auth_token  = "your_auth_token"
client = TwilioRestClient(account_sid, auth_token)

call = client.calls.create(url="http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml",
    to="+1XXXXXXXXXX", # Number verified with Twilio for trial account.
    from_="+1XXXXXXXXXX") 

print(call.sid)
```

and [send sms](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages) to test.

```
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient 

# put your own credentials here 
ACCOUNT_SID = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" 
AUTH_TOKEN = "your_auth_token" 

client = TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN) 

client.messages.create(
    to="+1XXXXXXXXXX", # Number verified with Twilio for trial account.
    from_="+1XXXXXXXXXX", 
    body="This is the ship that made the Kessel Run in fourteen parsecs?", 
    media_url="https://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2899/14341091933_1e92e62d12_b.jpg"

)
```